# Merge two CSV files Keeping duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, merge

I am trying to merge two csv files and keep duplicate records.  Each file may have a matching record, one file may have duplicate records (same student ID with different test scores), and one file may not have a matching student record in the other file.  The code below works as expected however if a duplicate record exists only the second record is being written to the merged file.  I've looked through many threads and all address removing duplicates but I need to keep duplicate records.

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
import os

cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

fafile = os.path.join(cd, 'MJB_FAScores.csv')
testscores = os.path.join(cd, 'MJB_TestScores.csv')

filenames = fafile, testscores
data = OrderedDict()
fieldnames = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
        fieldnames.extend(reader.fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            data.setdefault(row['Student_Number'], {}).update(row)
fieldnames = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(fieldnames))
with open('merged.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in data.values():
        writer.writerow([row.get(fields, '') for fields in fieldnames])
```

---

**fafile:**

```
Student_Number  Name    Grade   Teacher FA1 FA2 FA3
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    56  45  98
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    32  323 232
85250   Ball, Jonathan  3   Clarke, Mary    65  77  45
981235  Ball, David 5   Longo, Noel 56  89  23
91851   Ball, Jeff  0   Delaney, Mary   83  45  42
543 MAX 2   Phil    77  77  77
543 MAX 2   Annie   88  888 88
9844    Lisa    1   Smith, Jennifer 43  44  55
```

**testscores:**

```
Student_Number  Name    Grade   Teacher MAP Reading MAP Math    FP Level    DSA LN  DSA WW  DSA SJ  DSA DC
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    175 221 A   54  23  78  99
72941   Ball, Amanda    4   Bauman, Edyn    201 235 J   65  34  65
85250   Ball, Jonathan  3   Clarke, Mary    189 201 L   34  54
981235  Ball, David 5   Longo, Noel 225 231 D   23  55
91851   Ball, Jeff  0   Delaney, Mary   198 175 C
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    200 76  Y   54  23  78  99
543 MAX 2   Phil    111 111 Z   33  44  55  66
543 MAX 2   Annie   222 222 A   44  55  66  77
```

**Current output:**

```
Student_Number  Name    Grade   Teacher FA1 FA2 FA3 MAP Reading MAP Math    FP Level    DSA LN  DSA WW  DSA SJ  DSA DC
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    32  323 232 200 76  Y   54  23  78  99
85250   Ball, Jonathan  3   Clarke, Mary    65  77  45  189 201 L   34  54
981235  Ball, David 5   Longo, Noel 56  89  23  225 231 D   23  55
91851   Ball, Jeff  0   Delaney, Mary   83  45  42  198 175 C
543 MAX 2   Annie   88  888 88  222 222 A   44  55  66  77
72941   Ball, Amanda    4   Bauman, Edyn                201 235 J   65  34  65
9844    Lisa    1   Smith, Jennifer 43  44  55
```

**Desired output:**

```
Student_Number  Name    Grade   Teacher FA1 FA2 FA3 MAP Reading MAP Math    FP Level    DSA LN  DSA WW  DSA SJ  DSA DC
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    32  323 232 200 76  Y   54  23  78  99
65731   Ball, Peggy 4   Bauman, Edyn    56  45  98  175 221 A   54  23  78  99
85250   Ball, Jonathan  3   Clarke, Mary    65  77  45  189 201 L   34  54
981235  Ball, David 5   Longo, Noel 56  89  23  225 231 D   23  55
91851   Ball, Jeff  0   Delaney, Mary   83  45  42  198 175 C
543 MAX 2   Annie   88  888 88  222 222 A   44  55  66  77
543 MAX 2   Phil    77  77  77  111 111 Z   33  44  55  66
72941   Ball, Amanda    4   Bauman, Edyn                201 235 J   65  34  65
9844    Lisa    1   Smith, Jennifer 43  44  55
```

Comment: Your code produces a `KeyError: 'Student_Number'` on the line `data.setdefault(row['Student_Number'], {}).update(row)`.

Comment: Please clarify how you want the merging to occur. For example, there are two records in each file for student id `65731` for a total of four, but there are only two in the desired output. Why weren't all four kept?

Comment: Basically the data from the testscores file should append, horizontally, to the fafile matching on the Student_Number.  Each file contains different data sets and attempts to put all the test scores together for each student.  Some students take a test twice, or not at all, so may have 0, 1 or more records in each file. The final file should have these columns:  Student_Number, Name, Grade, Teacher, FA1, FA2, FA3, MAP Reading, Map Math, FP Level, DSA LN, DSA WW, DSA SJ, DSA DC.  If a student has no record in fafile but 2 in testscores they should have 2 rows of data with the "FAx" fields empty

Comment: You need to describe precisely how, given two record dictionaries with the same `'Student_Number'` key, the decision is made whether to merge them or not, and exactly how the should be done (what should be retained from each). Please [edit] your question and put it there, _not_ down here in the comments.

Comment: There should not be duplicate records however, this assumes the teachers entering data followed directions.  Unfortunately they did not and I'm not able to determine which test scores should not be kept-I can only present the data.  There is no correlation between the FA scores and the testscores other than a horizontal "list" of the scores available for that student.  It will be up to the principal to determine which test scores to evaluate for student progress.  For #65731 it doesn't matter which FA scores go with which test scores as long as they go with the correct student number.

Comment: What part of my request to put the description in your question was unclear? Regardless, consider adding it as a written out step-by-step procedure that given two dictionaries, `row1` and `row2`, with common 'Student_Number' key value, and a bunch of other keys they may or may not have in common, should be merged into a new third dictionary with keys and values from each one of the originals. Which key, value pairs from each are retained and why. If you can't even explain that, then writing a program to do it is going to be very difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `OrderedDict` to store student IDs (keys) and their record (values) from both files.

This has a subtle implication: new *student ID* entries will replace the old duplicate *student ID*  dict entries from the previous file, because dict keys are unique.

You may consider writing the entries to the *merge* file immediately after they are read from one file. After which the `dict` is cleared and the next file is used to *repopulate* `dict`. This will help avoid *collision* and *replacement* of studentIDs.

Answer (score 0):

For your inner loop you can do the following:

```
for row in reader:
    new_record = dict(row)
    records = data.setdefault(row['Student_Number'], [])
    for record in records:
        new_record.update(record) # preserve old values
        record = copy.copy(new_record) 
    new_record.update(dict(row)) # to preserve original values
    records.append(new_record)
```

When writing you have to go one step deeper now:

```
for rows in data.values():
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

A the beginning add "import copy". I wrote it from my head, may need some tweaking.

Basically what this does is adds another layer in form of list where you update your old values with new ones and add updated new record to the end of list with (all collected data are put into the new record). When writing it has to go one level deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for something like this, specifically [DataFrame.append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append)

First you would create a DataFrame for both CSVs using `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('filename')`.

Then append the DataFrames together: `myDataFrame.append(otherDataframe)`.

And finally output the result with `to_csv()`.

Putting it all together:
[image: Code snippet]